# Who is the boy from Katniss' hallucination?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-hunger-games, the-hunger-games-catching-fire

At the beginning of [*The Hunger Games: Catching Fire*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1951264/) when *Katniss* is hunting with *Gale*, she tries to shoot some birds. When shooting she suddenly imagines a boy getting hit by the arrow, much to her shock. This hallucination is likely part of her PTSD after the Hunger Games.

[image]

But I wonder, **was this actually a flashback of a particular tribute she killed during the first movie** or was this just some random boy she imagined to have killed now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a flashback of [Marvel](http://thehungergames.wikia.com/wiki/Marvel), the tribute who killed [Rue](http://thehungergames.wikia.com/wiki/Rue) in the first film. In retaliation, Katniss killed him. As a review of [this page](http://thehungergames.wikia.com/wiki/74th_Hunger_Games) shows, this was the first person she killed, which is likely why she is having flashbacks.